# How to increase the frame of the object? unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a question, I create a game that every time a player touches a flower something happens.
But I have a problem that the flower frame is very large so that in almost every movement the player touches the flowers. I've included a screenshot to explain this more.
In addition, I would love to know how after I touch the flower.
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using something like Box Collider, so you just need to adjust the size of the collider by clicking the edit collider button.

[image: Edit Box Collider]

Comment: Exactly !! Thank you

Comment: And how can I delete the flower after touching?

Comment: @טל זיידמ, it depends on where you're detecting the collision. If you're detecting the collision in a script that's attached to the flower, then after detecting the collision, just execute this line: `Destroy(gameObject);`.

Comment: Thank you very much